# use Gutenberg editor in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, gutenberg-blocks

I am looking for a way to create pages with blocks, like in wordpress visual composer or now gutenberg editor can do. I am not using wordpress. What I want to do for example is the following layout of a page:

- Full width image (set as parallax).
- Then a text block.
- Another full width image (parallax but smaller in height).
- Two extra text blocks.

I am using cakephp 3.

Is there an editor that can do this on an easy way?

Cheers